# Why can't the program recognize pygame?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I have downloaded and installed pygame and I know where it is (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages). I am trying to get the program consisting of the line 'import pygame' to recognize its existence but I keep getting 'ImportError: No module named pygame'. How would I get it to work?

Comment: You named your own fault; you are using a 2.7 package in a 3.x environment. This will likely cause incompatibility issues. The specific error you are getting states that the installed package is not in your python3's PATH.

Comment: Would generally suggest using 2.7 over 3. Better support

Comment: Pygame was downloaded today from the Ubuntu website so I'm assuming it's the latest stable version. But how do I get 'import pygame' to work?

Comment: use python 2 instead of 3, afaik pygame doesn't support python 3 at all

Comment: Pygame supports python3. https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads

Comment: You have to qualify that statement - taken literally it contradicts ecline6's answer below, which was posted earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation packages for pygame are incompatible with python 3.x  However, the vast majority of the pygame modules have been ported to python 3.x, so really it's simply a matter of moving the Pygame modules to your python 3.x dist-packages.

The scrap, _movie, surfarray for Numeric, and threads modules are the ones that have NOT been ported yet.

Comment: That makes sense, for now I have followed Ryan Haining's suggestion and got 'import pygame' to work in python 2.7.